# On click How can I cycle through JSON one by one in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Creating my first directive as an exercise in angular —making more or less a custom carousel to learn how directives work.

I've set up a Factory with some JSON data:

```
directiveApp.factory("Actors", function(){
var Actors = {};
Actors.detail = {
    "1": {
      "name": "Russel Brand",
      "profession": "Actor",
      "yoga": [
        "Bikram",
        "Hatha",
        "Vinyasa"
      ]
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "Aaron Bielefeldt",
      "profession": "Ambassador",
      "yoga": [
        "Bikram",
        "Hatha",
        "Vinyasa"
      ]
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "Adrienne Hengels",
      "profession": "Ambassador",
      "yoga": [
        "Bikram",
        "Hatha",
        "Vinyasa"
      ]
    }
  };
  return Actors;
});
```

And an actors controller:

```
function actorsCtrl($scope, Actors) {
    $scope.actors = Actors;
  }
```

And am using ng-repeat to display the model data:

```
<div ng-controller="actorsCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="actor in actors.detail">
    <p>{{actor.name}} </p>
  </div>
      <div ng-click="next-actor">Next Actor</div>
</div>
```

1) How do I only display the actor's name in the first index of my angular model `actors.detail`?

2) How do I properly create a click event that will fetch the following index and replace the previous `actor.name`

User flow:

- Russell Brand is Visible
- click of `next-actor` ->Russell Brand's name is replaced with Aaron Bielefeldt

Comment: why dont you make an array of actors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want the current user, the ng-repeat is not what you want to use, since that would be for each element in the data;

You would want to keep track of the index you are looking at in the scope, and increment that.

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    {{data[current].name}}
    <div ng-click="Next();"> NEXT! </div>
</div>
```

Where in the controller we also have these set up, where data is your actors:

```
$scope.current = 0;
$scope.Next = function() {
    $scope.current = ($scope.current + 1) % $scope.data.length;
};
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgL5P/) where it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I would change my serivce to return a single actor and maintain the index in the controller. 
something like [this](http://jsbin.com/egaBIho/1/edit?html,js,console,output). This is an incomplete solution - you need to take care of cycle etc...