# Click throug JSON Object - Previous Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am referring to this question/answer:

[On click How can I cycle through JSON one by one in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439439/on-click-how-can-i-cycle-through-json-one-by-one-in-angularjs)

I am searching a function, which shows the previous item from a JSON Object - And when the first is selected it should show the last one after clicking. I tried to modify the code following:

```
$scope.current = 0;
$scope.Back = function() {
$scope.current = ($scope.current - 1) % $scope.data.length;
};
```

But when the first one is selected and I click on this it shows me nothing. So how I have to modify this function that i have also a 'back-function' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check weather your $scope.current value is 0. If so ,make your current to data.length - 1.

```
$scope.current = ($scope.current == 0)? $scope.data.length-1 : ($scope.current - 1) % $scope.data.length;
```